# How can I create a drop down menu bar for mobile viewing?

Tags: mobile, navigationbar, menubar

```css
@charset "UTF-8";



/* ----------------- Reset all styles ----------------- */
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0;
}

/* ----------------- Website background and general text colour ----------------- */
body{
 background-image:url(../images/backgroundtexture.png);
 background-color:#f9f9f9;
 color:#2d2d2d;
}


/* ----------------- Wrapper - keeps all content in the center of page -----------------  */
.wrapper{
 margin:auto;
 width:80%;
 height:auto;
}


/* The rest is pretty self explanatory - it appears in the order that it occurs on the HTML document */
#top{
 height:40px;
}

#logo{
 margin-top:5%;
 text-decoration:none;
}

#logoimage{
 width:222px;
 padding-right:126px;
 float:left;
}


#logotitle{
 float:left;
 font-family: Candara;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:215%;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #FFF;
}

#logotitle a{
 color:#9933cc;
 text-decoration:none;
}

nav{
 float:right;
 width:70%;
 display:block;
 height:40px;
}

nav ul li{
 display:block;
 width:14%;
 float:left;
 text-align:center; 
}

nav ul li a{
 font-family: Candara;
 width:70%;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:400;
 line-height:250%;
 display:block;
 color:#9933cc;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
 color:#4B0082;
}

nav ul li p{
 font-family: Candara;
 width:70%;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:400;
 line-height:250%;
 display:block;
 color:#9933cc;
}

hr{
 height:1px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#9933cc;
 margin:3% 0;
}

header{
 width:100%;
 margin:5% 0 5% 0;
}

header h1{
 font-family: Candara;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:140%;
 font-weight:normal;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 margin-bottom:1%;
}

header h1 span{
 color:#9933cc;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #dadada;
}

header h2{
 font-family: Candara;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:100%;
 font-weight:normal;
}
 
#slideshow{
 width:100%;
 margin-top:2%;
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  Slider START  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

.html_carousel {
}
.html_carousel div.slide {
 position: relative;
} 
.html_carousel div.slide img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c1c1c1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c1c1c1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c1c1c1;
 border-radius:15px;
}

.clearfix {
 float: none;
 clear: both;
}

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  Slider END  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

.eva{
 margin-left:10%;
}

.left{
 margin-top:4%;
 width:48%;
 float:left;
 margin-bottom:2%;
}

.left h3{
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:180%;
 font-weight:normal;
 text-align:center;
 color:#9933cc;
 margin-bottom:5%;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #dadada;
}

.left ol{
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:100%;
 line-height:140%;
 font-weight:normal;
 //text-align:rigth;
 margin-bottom:5%; 
}

.left p{
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:100%;
 line-height:140%;
 text-align:justify;
}

.left p a{
 color:#9933cc;
 text-decoration:none;
}
 
.right{
 margin-top:4%;
 width:48%;
 float:right;
 margin-bottom:2%;
}

.right h3{
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:180%;
 font-weight:normal;
 text-align:center;
 color:#9933cc;
 margin-bottom:5%;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #dadada;
}

.right p{
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:100%;
 line-height:140%;
 text-align:justify;
}

.right p a{
 color:#9933cc;
 text-decoration:none;
}


/* ----------------------- WORK LINKS START ------------------------- */
#work{
 width:800px;
 margin:3% auto 3% auto;
}

.item{
 border-radius:15px;
 width:180px;
 height:185px;
 background-color:#FFF;
 margin:10px;
 float:left;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #c3c3c3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #c3c3c3;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #c3c3c3;  
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #9933cc, 0 0 8px #9933cc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #9933cc,  0 0 8px #9933cc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #9933cc,  0 0 8px #9933cc; 
}
 

.item img{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #c3c3c3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #c3c3c3;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #c3c3c3;
 border-radius:15px 15px 0 0;
 opacity:0.8;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
 
}

.item img:hover{
 opacity:1;
}


.item h3{
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:105%;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:5px 0 0 8px;
 color:#2d2d2d;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.item h3 a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#2d2d2d;
}

.item p{
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:70%;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:0 0 0 8px;
 color:#9933cc;
 text-decoration:none;
}
/* ----------------------- WORK LINKS END ------------------------- */


#bottom h3{
 margin:4% 0 3% 0;
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:190%;
 font-weight:normal;
 text-align:center;
 color:#9933cc;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c1c1c1;
}


footer{
 width:100%;
 padding:10px 0;
 background-color:#2d2d2d;
}

.icon{
 float:right;
 width:32px;
 margin:95px 0 2px 4%;
 opacity:0.85;
}

.icon:hover{
 opacity:1;
}

.social{
 color:#9933cc;
}


/* ----------------------------- FORM ----------------------------------- */

.left h4{
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:180%;
 font-weight:normal;
 color:#9933cc;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}

#formwrap{
 width:100%;
}

.formstyle { 
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 color: #000;
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:14px;
 width: 95%;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
 background-image:url(../images/backgroundtexture.png);
 margin-bottom:10px;
 opacity:0.9;
 padding:3px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   border-radius:2px;
}

.formstyletwo { 
 color: #9933cc;
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:15px;
 text-align:left;
 width:20%;
 background-color:#2d2d2d;
 border:0px;
 
}

.formstyletwo:hover { 
 color:#f38094;
 cursor:pointer;

}

textarea{ 
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 color: #000;
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size:14px;
 width:95%;
 height:80px;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
 background-image:url(../images/backgroundtexture.png);
 margin-bottom:10px;
 border-radius:2px;
 padding:3px;
 opacity:0.9;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}


input:focus, input.focused, textarea:focus, textarea.focused {  color: #3e3e3e; opacity:1;}

#error{
 color:#FF7471;
 float:left;
 font-family:Regular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, "Helvetica Neue Light";
 font-size:15px;
}

#error ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding-top:5px;
}
 

/* -- Make the highlight colours pretty -- */
::selection      { background:#f38094; color:#FFF;}
::-moz-selection  { background:#9933cc; color:#FFF;}




/* ---------------------- RESPONSIVE STUFF - ONLY TOUCH IF YOUR'E CONFIDENT WITH CSS ---------------------- */


@media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) {
 .wrapper{
  width:90%;
 }
 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1105px) {
 
 #work{
  width:900px;
}

 .item{
  width:164px;
  height:170px;
  margin:8px;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
 
 #work{
  width:750px; 
}

 .item{
  width:136px;
  height:144px;
  margin:7px;
 }
 
 .item h3{
  font-size:90%;
 }
 
 .item p{
  font-size:60%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 835px) {
 
 #work{
  width:650px; 
}

 .item{
  width:116px;
  height:121px;
  margin:7px;
 }
 
 .item h3{
  font-size:75%;
 }
 
 .item p{
  font-size:40%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
 header h1{
  font-size:110%;
 }
 
 header h2{
  font-size:80%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
 
 #logo{
  width:150px;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  margin-bottom:5%;
 }
 
 nav{
  width:100%;
 }
 
 header h1{
  font-size:100%;
  margin-bottom:5%;
 }
 
 header h2{
  font-size:60%;
 }
 
 .left{
  width:100%;
 }
 
 .right{
  width:100%;
 
 }
 
 #work{
  width:460px; 
}

 .item{
  width:210px;
  height:215px;
  margin:10px;
 }
 
 .item h3{
  font-size:130%;
 }
 
 .item p{
  font-size:90%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 510px) {
 
 #work{
  width:300px; 
 }

 .item{
  width:136px;
  height:140px;
  margin:7px;
 }
 
 .item h3{
  font-size:75%;
 }
 
 .item p{
  font-size:40%;
 }
}
```

I don't have css code created for a menu/navigation bar to appear when pages are viewed on a mobile device. (So right now all the text overlaps and jumbles when viewed on a phone.)

Does anyone have code that can give me a basic menu/navigation bar for mobile devices. (I am NOT a coder. Just a volunteer helping run this page.)

The pages on this website are all running on one css code (included here). I would like help on a second css code that I could apply for mobile viewing.

This is the css that all the pages run.

```
@charset "UTF-8";



/* ----------------- Reset all styles ----------------- */
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}

/* ----------------- Website background and general text colour ----------------- */
body{
    background-image:url(../images/backgroundtexture.png);
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    color:#2d2d2d;
}


/* ----------------- Wrapper - keeps all content in the center of page -----------------  */
.wrapper{
    margin:auto;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
}


/* The rest is pretty self explanatory - it appears in the order that it occurs on the HTML document */
#top{
    height:40px;
}

#logo{
    margin-top:5%;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#logoimage{
    width:222px;
    padding-right:126px;
    float:left;
}


#logotitle{
    float:left;
    font-family: Candara;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:215%;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #FFF;
}

#logotitle a{
    color:#9933cc;
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav{
    float:right;
    width:70%;
    display:block;
    height:40px;
}

nav ul li{
    display:block;
    width:14%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;  
}

nav ul li a{
    font-family: Candara;
    width:70%;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height:250%;
    display:block;
    color:#9933cc;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#4B0082;
}

nav ul li p{
    font-family: Candara;
    width:70%;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height:250%;
    display:block;
    color:#9933cc;
}

hr{
    height:1px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#9933cc;
    margin:3% 0;
}

header{
    width:100%;
    margin:5% 0 5% 0;
}

header h1{
    font-family: Candara;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:140%;
    font-weight:normal;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    margin-bottom:1%;
}

header h1 span{
    color:#9933cc;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #dadada;
}

header h2{
    font-family: Candara;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}

#slideshow{
    width:100%;
    margin-top:2%;
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  Slider START  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

.html_carousel {
}
.html_carousel div.slide {
    position: relative;
}   
.html_carousel div.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c1c1c1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c1c1c1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c1c1c1;
    border-radius:15px;
}

.clearfix {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  Slider END  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

.eva{
    margin-left:10%;
}

.left{
    margin-top:4%;
    width:48%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:2%;
}

.left h3{
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:180%;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:center;
    color:#9933cc;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #dadada;
}

.left ol{
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:100%;
    line-height:140%;
    font-weight:normal;
    //text-align:rigth;
    margin-bottom:5%;   
}

.left p{
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:100%;
    line-height:140%;
    text-align:justify;
}

.left p a{
    color:#9933cc;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.right{
    margin-top:4%;
    width:48%;
    float:right;
    margin-bottom:2%;
}

.right h3{
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:180%;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:center;
    color:#9933cc;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #dadada;
}

.right p{
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:100%;
    line-height:140%;
    text-align:justify;
}

.right p a{
    color:#9933cc;
    text-decoration:none;
}


/* ----------------------- WORK LINKS START ------------------------- */
#work{
    width:800px;
    margin:3% auto 3% auto;
}

.item{
    border-radius:15px;
    width:180px;
    height:185px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #c3c3c3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #c3c3c3;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #c3c3c3;  
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #9933cc, 0 0 8px #9933cc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #9933cc,  0 0 8px #9933cc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #9933cc,  0 0 8px #9933cc; 
}


.item img{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #c3c3c3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #c3c3c3;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #c3c3c3;
    border-radius:15px 15px 0 0;
    opacity:0.8;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;

}

.item img:hover{
    opacity:1;
}


.item h3{
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:105%;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:5px 0 0 8px;
    color:#2d2d2d;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.item h3 a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#2d2d2d;
}

.item p{
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:70%;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:0 0 0 8px;
    color:#9933cc;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* ----------------------- WORK LINKS END ------------------------- */


#bottom h3{
    margin:4% 0 3% 0;
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:190%;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:center;
    color:#9933cc;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c1c1c1;
}


footer{
    width:100%;
    padding:10px 0;
    background-color:#2d2d2d;
}

.icon{
    float:right;
    width:32px;
    margin:95px 0 2px 4%;
    opacity:0.85;
}

.icon:hover{
    opacity:1;
}

.social{
    color:#9933cc;
}


/* ----------------------------- FORM ----------------------------------- */

.left h4{
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:180%;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#9933cc;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#formwrap{
    width:100%;
}

.formstyle { 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:14px;
    width: 95%;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background-image:url(../images/backgroundtexture.png);
    margin-bottom:10px;
    opacity:0.9;
    padding:3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   border-radius:2px;
}

.formstyletwo { 
    color: #9933cc;
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color:#2d2d2d;
    border:0px;

}

.formstyletwo:hover { 
    color:#f38094;
    cursor:pointer;

}

textarea{ 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Candara;
    font-size:14px;
    width:95%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background-image:url(../images/backgroundtexture.png);
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-radius:2px;
    padding:3px;
    opacity:0.9;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}


input:focus, input.focused, textarea:focus, textarea.focused {  color: #3e3e3e; opacity:1;}

#error{
    color:#FF7471;
    float:left;
    font-family:Regular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, "Helvetica Neue Light";
    font-size:15px;
}

#error ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top:5px;
}


/* -- Make the highlight colours pretty -- */
::selection      { background:#f38094; color:#FFF;}
::-moz-selection  { background:#9933cc; color:#FFF;}




/* ---------------------- RESPONSIVE STUFF - ONLY TOUCH IF YOUR'E CONFIDENT WITH CSS ---------------------- */


@media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) {
    .wrapper{
        width:90%;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1105px) {

    #work{
        width:900px;
}

    .item{
        width:164px;
        height:170px;
        margin:8px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {

    #work{
        width:750px;    
}

    .item{
        width:136px;
        height:144px;
        margin:7px;
    }

    .item h3{
        font-size:90%;
    }

    .item p{
        font-size:60%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 835px) {

    #work{
        width:650px;    
}

    .item{
        width:116px;
        height:121px;
        margin:7px;
    }

    .item h3{
        font-size:75%;
    }

    .item p{
        font-size:40%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
    header h1{
        font-size:110%;
    }

    header h2{
        font-size:80%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {

    #logo{
        width:150px;
        display:block;
        margin:auto;
        margin-bottom:5%;
    }

    nav{
        width:100%;
    }

    header h1{
        font-size:100%;
        margin-bottom:5%;
    }

    header h2{
        font-size:60%;
    }

    .left{
        width:100%;
    }

    .right{
        width:100%;

    }

    #work{
        width:460px;    
}

    .item{
        width:210px;
        height:215px;
        margin:10px;
    }

    .item h3{
        font-size:130%;
    }

    .item p{
        font-size:90%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 510px) {

    #work{
        width:300px;    
    }

    .item{
        width:136px;
        height:140px;
        margin:7px;
    }

    .item h3{
        font-size:75%;
    }

    .item p{
        font-size:40%;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the actual page. http://ventricular.org/CORTICALEVOLUTION2018/corticalevolution2018.html

Comment: I found this tutorial, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp, but I'm not sure how I would incorporate it into the html I already have.